# Unexpected Token '<' Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

He tenido errores en el envío de mi formulario a archivo html, la línea 19 `var json  = eval("(" + data + ")");` me la marca en mi archivo siguiente:

```
<script language="javascript">
var posting_date = null;
function cargar_push()
{
$.ajax({
    async:  true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "validar.php",
    data: "&posting_date="+posting_date,
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data)
    {
        var json  = eval("(" + data + ")");
        count    = json.count;

        if(posting_date == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
            async:  true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "mensajes.php",
            data: " ",
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#div1').html(data);
            }
            });
         }
         setTimeout('cargar_push()',1000);

      }
     });
     }

     $(document).ready(function()
    {

    cargar_push();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Añade por favor la respuesta del servidor, ya que ahí es donde está el problema.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que estás intentando *reconvertir* la respuesta que **jQuery** ya transformó en objeto (`eval("(" + data + ")")` es la manera *nativa* en que `JSON.parse` trabaja). Omite esa línea y cuéntanos que pasa.

Comment: Verifica que el servidor devuelva un JSON realmente. En JS cambia el tipo de dato poniendo esto: `dataType:"json"`  y ya está, no tienes necesidad de usar `eval` para esto, es una función peligrosa y no deberías usarla en este contexto.